# How to run my CPU at a given percentage?

Tags: power-management, cpu

I need to establish the relation between the electricity consumption and the usage of the CPU of my computer using voltmeter and by scaling the CPU usage percentage.

I don't want to simply measure minimal CPU usage and maximal CPU usage and  assume linearity. I want to gradually change the CPU usage percentage.

What would you suggest to run?

PS: to run at 100%, I run

```
for i in 1 2 3 4
do
    (
        while true
        do
            i+=1 
        done
    ) &
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `matho-primes` for simulating high CPU usage and `cpulimit` tool to set maximum CPU load. Example:

```
cpulimit -l 50 matho-primes 0 9999999999 > /dev/null &
```

which should use 50 percent of CPU.

source: http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2014/11/04/restricting-process-cpu-usage-using-nice-cpulimit-and-cgroups

Answer (score 0):

I would use `stress`, which allows you to configure an amount of CPU to consume. Webpage here: http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~apw/stress/

You can install it with `sudo apt-get install stress`.

Comment: `stress` just allows you to specify a number of CPU worker threads, each of them will consume always a full logical core (e.g. a dual-core CPU with hyperthreading has 4 logical cores - so `stress -c 4` would cause 100% CPU usage). There is no option to tune CPU usage in a linear way.

Comment: Good call. Misinterpretation of the man page on my part.